# VB SqlConnection object missing

Tags: vb.net, sqlconnection

Win 11 vers: 10.0.22621

VS 2022 vers: 17.7.4

Net. 4.8.0902

SQL Server vers: 15.0.2101.7

Both VS and SQL are on the same pc.

I'm an old vb programmer and a cannot figure out how to connect to SQL Server via:
'Dim cn as New SqlConnection'
The intellisense does not list the connection object.
Can you please point me to some instructions on how to resolve this?
Thank you for your time.

Poked around the internet but could not find any solutions.

Comment: [System.Data.SqlClient - NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/)

Comment: It's all explained here(the `Imports System.Data.SqlClient` too): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/dotnet/framework/general/open-database-by-sql-server-dotnet-data-provider

Comment: @Jimi, there should be no need to install a NuGet package. The question says "Net. 4.8.0902" so that is presumably .NET Framework 4.8.x, so `SqlClient` would be accessed by referencing System.Data.dll, which has probably already been done by default.

Comment: You should read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html). Accessing any type in .NET involves the same steps, so you should understand the principles involved or you'll end up in the same situation again with another type.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It should, if the information provided is correct. It also says that the VS version in use is the latest, so when you write something like `var con = new SqlConnection([...]);`, VS adds eventually missing `using` / `Imports` directives automatically or suggests whether to install a missing package. It was just a *suggestion*, anyway, to get some feedback from the OP

Comment: @Jimi, if you want some feedback from the OP, you probably ought to ask them a question, rather than just providing a link as though that's the solution to their problem somehow.

Comment: Thank you all.  The System.Data.dll is automatically referenced. If I import System.Data.SqlClient is appears light gray, signifying it is already included.  Allow me to add that this is a forms app, not console.

Comment: @OldProgrammerJoe Not sure you understand what the `Imports` keyword does. It just saves you typing out the whole classname with namespace e.g. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`

Answer (score 0):

If you start a new .NET Framework 4.8 Console App, the following code should work. Replace `MyDatabaseName` with the name of your database and `MyTableName` with the name of your table.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1    
  Sub Main()
    Dim connectionString = "Data Source=(local);Timeout=10;Database=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;"
    Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM MyTableName"
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
      cnn.Open()
      Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, cnn)
        dad.Fill(dtb)
      End Using
      cnn.Close()
    End Using
    Dim firstRow = dtb.Rows(0)
    For col = 0 To dtb.Columns.Count - 1
      Dim columnName = dtb.Columns(col).ColumnName
      Dim columnValue = CStr(firstRow(columnName))
      Console.WriteLine($"{columnName}={columnValue}")
    Next col       
  End Sub    
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The issue is that the 'SqlConneciton' object does not appear.  When typed it gets a red line under it. As above the System.Data.SqlClient is included and does not need to be Imported. Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't using `Imports` then you might need to include the namespace of the class. Try `Using cnn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)`